# Find and Replace of All Names

Tags: rename, replace

**Background**

I am new to linux/unix (I'm on a mac. Don't know which I am using), but someone made a lot of folders and files under the wrong name, and I need to go in and replace everything with the correct name. E.g. she named it apple instead of orange.

**What I need to do**

I navigated to the directory of interest, and within that directory, I need to:

1. Replace the word apple with orange in the name of any subfolder or file or directory
2. Replace the word apple with orange within any files (both text and non-text)

**What I have tried**

I tried this command:

> grep -lr "apple" . | xargs sed -i "s/apple/orange/g"

and that didn't work at all

I also tried :

> find ./ -exec sed -i 's/apple/orange/g' {} \;

This replaced a lot of the instances, but not all. And it does not replace the word within file/folder/directory names

Please help!

Comment: Just a guess: mac comes with bsd-sed (without -i option); often gnu seg is available with the name gsed, gnused, or you install it...

Comment: both of your examples only work on the contents of a file.  to rename files, you will need a separate command.  you will want to use `find` to get all files with `apple` in the name, then for each of those files, use `mv` to rename the file changing `apple` to `orange`.

Comment: Thank you, MikeA! I was hoping there was a shortcut so I could rename all the files at once. Glad either way to know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more BASHy then is possible, but maybe it will help toward the right direction.

In short, find all the folders with apple, reverse the sort so that

> /tmp/apple/test/apple

doesn't cause trouble when the first "apple" is changed out of order.
Next feed the output into a while loop with the read function loading up a variable that holds all the folders that match.  Finally, mv the folders into the right name structure.

for directories, try

> find ./ -regex '^.*apple' -type d | sort -r | while read badname ; do  mv $badname ${badname/%apple/orange}; done

for file names, (after directories are cleaned up )

> find ./ -regex '^.*apple.*' -type f | sort -r | while read badname ; do mv $badname ${badname/apple/orange}; done

for file content there are many other examples of that,

[Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)